# Error en la consulta: Column 'player_steamid' in where clause is ambiguous

Tags: php, mysqli

Estoy realizando una consulta, pero a la hora de clic para verificar esa consulta me salta el error *Error en la consulta: Column 'player_steamid' in where clause is ambiguous*

```php
$ext_query = "";
if(isset($_GET['status'])) {
    $ext_query = " where player_steamid='".$_GET['status']."'";
}

if(!isset($_GET['status'])) 
{
    $player_stid = "STEAM_0:1:555532380";
}
else 
{
    $player_stid = $_GET['status'];
}

$dbTable = "pug_globalplayerstats";
$query = $db->query('SELECT * FROM '.$dbTable) or die ("Error: ".mysqli_error($db));

$query = $db->query(
    'SELECT pug_globalplayerstats.*, pug_serverstats.pug_index, pug_serverstats.pug_hash, 
    pug_serverstats.pug_in_fecha, pug_serverstats.pug_svname 
    FROM pug_globalplayerstats 
    LEFT JOIN pug_playerstats ON pug_playerstats.player_steamid = pug_globalplayerstats.player_steamid 
    LEFT JOIN pug_serverstats ON pug_serverstats.pug_index = pug_playerstats.pug_index 
    '.$ext_query.' 
    ORDER BY player_kills DESC'
) or die ("Error en la consulta: ".mysqli_error($db));
// ^-- el error se ocasiona aqui en esta consulta de arriba
```

Answer (score 0):

El mismo nombre de la columna `player_steamid`, aparece en las tablas `pug_globalplayerstats` y `pug_globalplayerstats` , por lo cual en la línea 3 debes de elejir a qué tabla referenciar. Ejemplo:

```
$ext_query = " where pug_playerstats.player_steamid='".$_GET['status']."'";
```

Comment: lo coloque así **$ext_query = " where pug_globalplayerstats.player_steamid='".$_GET['status']."'";** pero a la hora de consultar el dato me sale 2 veces la misma consulta cuando solo debería ser 1

Comment: Entonces eso ya es la lógica de tu query como tal. Ese es otro tema. Prueba a usar SELECT DISTINCT